# Decltype cast operator in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, decltype

Consider following code example:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class T, class U>
struct lazy_caller{
    lazy_caller(T &&one, U &&two) : m_one(one), m_two(two){} 

    operator decltype(std::max(T(), U()))() const {
        return std::max(m_one, m_two);
    }

    T m_one;
    U m_two;
};

int main()
{
    lazy_caller<int, int> caller(1, 2);
    int i = caller;
    return 0;
}
```

As you may imagine, in real code I wanted to do more sophisticated type deduction to create appropriate conversion operator. Anyway - this code does not compile in VS2017 (and I guess the same is with earlier ones) - and so I would like to ask if there is any workaround for this issue? I have already tried:

```
operator auto () const
```

It also generates compiler errors like:

```
source_file.cpp(8): error C2833: 'operator function-style cast' is not a recognized operator or type
```

Is there any solution for this problem with msvc? 
Because gcc has not problem with neither `operator auto` nor `operator decltype(..)`.

Comment: There is no function max<T, U> in the C++ Standard.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but it still does not compile with two ints

Comment: It's a bug in the MS compiler. Not a big deal, you should avoid implicit conversions anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any solution for this problem with msvc?

What about passing through an `using` alias?

```
using maxType = decltype(std::max(T(), U()));

operator maxType () const {
    return std::max(m_one, m_two);
}
```

or, maybe better, using `std::declval()`,

```
using maxType = decltype(std::max(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()));
```

If this doesn't work, you can try with a third defaulted template type for the `lazy_caller` class; something like

```
template <typename T, typename U,
   typename R = decltype(std::max(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()))>
struct lazy_caller
 {
   lazy_caller(T && one, U && two) : m_one(one), m_two(two)
    { } 

   operator R () const
    { return std::max(m_one, m_two); }

   T m_one;
   U m_two;
 };
```

Comment: Just to clarify - the first two also do not work, but the last one is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You were very close with `operator auto () const`. This suggested [workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/152822/view.html) involves using C++11 function syntax:

```
operator auto() const -> decltype(std::max(T(), U())) {
    return std::max(m_one, m_two);
}
```